# Spring Boot + Apache Camel + Freemarker Custom Template Loader

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, freemarker

I am trying to create a Spring Boot application involving Apache Camel.

The Camel routes consists of a transformation of message using FreeMarker Template (for this I am using Camel's Freemarker integration)

```
from("direct:temporary").routeId("hello").to("freemarker:db:test-spot").end().to("stream:out");
```

The Freemarker templates are stored in Database and I am trying to load it using a Custom Template Loader (say DBTemplateLoader)

However, I haven't been successful yet! Reasons, even if I register my custom template loader, it resorts back to FreeMarkerComponent to load the templates, and of course it doesn't know my database.

Here is the error I am getting

```
freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "db:test-spot".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: org.apache.camel.component.freemarker.FreemarkerComponent$1@3dbbfc3a.
```

I have tried most of the resources on web. All these things work nicely isolation, but the Apache Camel + FreeeMarker + Custom Template Loader for Freemarker is just not working.

If anyone can point me to the right direction, then I would be grateful.

Comment: Probably you should check in the source code how Camel gets the `Template` to execute. Maybe it doesn't use `Configuration.getTemplate`, so the `TemplateLoader` is never involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register custom configuration globally to component, which is then applied to all freemarker endpoints. Or locally to single endpoint using `configuration` URI param.

**Register configuration to component:**

```
FreemarkerComponent freemarkerComponent = getContext().getComponent("freemarker", FreemarkerComponent.class);
freemarkerComponent.setConfiguration(myConfiguration);
```

**Register configuration to single endpoint:**

```
.to("freemarker:dummy?configuration=#freemarkerConfiguration") // freemarkerConfiguration is custom bean in registry
```

---

**I have created unit test for demonstration:**

```
public class CamelCustomFreemarkerLoader extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                Configuration myConfiguration = new Configuration();
                StringTemplateLoader dummyLoader = new StringTemplateLoader();
                dummyLoader.putTemplate("dummy", "Hello from dummy template");
                myConfiguration.setTemplateLoader(dummyLoader);

                FreemarkerComponent freemarkerComponent = getContext().getComponent("freemarker", FreemarkerComponent.class);
                freemarkerComponent.setConfiguration(myConfiguration);

                from("direct:test")
                        .to("freemarker:dummy")
                        .to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testCustomTemplateLoader() throws Exception{
        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        template.sendBody("direct:test",null);
        mockEndpoint.setExpectedCount(1);
        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello from dummy template", mockEndpoint.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am hopeful that this is gonna work. I really appreciate your hard work into this solution. I will try and let you know..

Comment: @dharam, I'd appreciate if you guys could look at my question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220213/unit-testing-freemarker-templates-in-springboot-unable-to-initialize-freemarke - hopefully either of you would know..