# Unit Testing Freemarker templates in SpringBoot - unable to initialize freemarker configuration

Tags: spring-boot, junit, freemarker, junit5

we are using Freemarker for generating the HTML code for the emails our application is going to be sending.

Our usage and configuration is based off of https://github.com/hdineth/SpringBoot-freemaker-email-send
Particularly:

```
package com.example.techmagister.sendingemail.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean;

import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class FreemarkerConfig {

    @Bean(name="emailConfigBean")
    public FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean getFreeMarkerConfiguration(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean bean = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean();
        bean.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/templates/");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

However, there is absolutely no information or documentation anywhere, about how to run Unit Tests for this using JUnit 5.

When I added the relevant dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

versions:

```
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.3.1</junit.jupiter.version>
        <mockito.version>2.23.0</mockito.version>
```

And made a test class:

```
package com.example.techmagister.sendingemail;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.Template;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import java.io.IOException;


@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
@Import(com.example.techmagister.sendingemail.config.FreemarkerConfig.class)
public class EmailTestTest {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(EmailTestTest.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("emailConfigBean")
    private Configuration emailConfig;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        try {
            Template template = emailConfig.getTemplate("email.ftl");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When I run that in debug mode, `emailConfig` is null.
Why is that?

Their test example https://github.com/hdineth/SpringBoot-freemaker-email-send/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/techmagister/sendingemail/SendingemailApplicationTests.java
works if I add the same autowired property, but it is a full SprintBoot context that is slow to boot, and I need to test just template usage, without actually sending out the email.

In our actual code (which is large, multi module project), I have another error `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException`
caused by:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'freemarker.template.Configuration' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=emailConfigBean)}
```

But that is just for context, first I want to get it working in the simple, sample project then worry about getting it working in our complex one.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot autowire your `emailConfigBean` directly as a `freemarker.template.Configuration`
`FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean` is a factorybean.
To get the `Confuguration` you need to call factorybean.getObject()

so instead of

```java
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("emailConfigBean")
    private Configuration emailConfig;
```

just autowire your factorybean `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean` and load your template with `emailConfig.getObject().getTemplate("email.ftl")`

```java
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("emailConfigBean")
    private FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean emailConfig;

    @Test
    void testFreemarkerTemplate(){
        Assertions.assertNotNull(emailConfig);
        try {
            Template template =
                emailConfig
                    .getObject()               // <-- get the configuration
                    .getTemplate("email.ftl"); // <-- load the template
            Assertions.assertNotNull(template);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

working test on [github](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/freemarker-junit5/tree/master)

---

On the other hand...
In a Spring Boot application the Freemarker configuration can be simplified by using the `spring-boot-starter-freemarker` dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This starter for building MVC web applications using FreeMarker views adds the necessary auto-configuration. All you need to do is placing your template files in the `resources/templates` folder.

Then you just can autowire the `freemarkerConfig` (*or use constructor injection*):

```java
    @Autowired
    private Configuration freemarkerConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice example here, in the attached github code. I was able to use it as a starting point to test my freeMarker code: https://cleantestcode.wordpress.com/2014/06/01/unit-testing-freemarker-templates/